# Do two close functions share some local minima?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be two differentiable functions. Assume that $\| f -g \|_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$. On what conditions on $f$, for every local minima $x$ of $g$, there is a local minimum $x'$ of $f$, such that, $\| x - x'\| \leq \mathcal{O}(h(\epsilon))$ for some positive function $h(\epsilon) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ (or at least $\| x - x'\| \leq \text{const}$)? I thought maybe $\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla g(x)\|_{\infty}\leq \epsilon$ might be sufficient.

Comment: I don't know that there is an answer, but consider the example $g(x)=f(x)+\frac\epsilon2\sin(nx)$ for different (large) $n$.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't violate the second assumption on the gradients. I'm also interested in the conditions for which this implication holds.

Comment: Beware that minima usually exhibit a parabolic behavior, so that a change of $\epsilon$ on $y$ corresponds to a change of $\sqrt \epsilon$ on $x$.

Comment: I'm fine with something that is not $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$. I actually want it to be $\mathcal{O}(h(\epsilon))$ for some $h(\epsilon) \geq 0$ and $h(\epsilon) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @YvesDaoust